# NetworkStream doesn't flush data

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm writing a simple chat program using sockets. When I'm sending a long message, flush the stream and a short message afterwards, the end of the long message gets appended to the short message. It looks like this:

Send "aaasdsd"

Recieve "aaasdsd"

Send "bb"

Recieve "bb**asdsd**"

Through debugging I've found that the Flush method, that's supposed to clear all data from the stream, does not do that. According to mdsn, it is the expected behaviour, because NetworkStream is not bufferized. How do I clear the stream in that case? I could just follow every message with an empty (consisting of \0 chars) one of the same length, but I don't think it's correct to do that, also, it would screw up some features I need.

Comment: I suspect you've misdiagnosed the issue - I think, instead, you're re-using the buffer at the receiving end and not checking the return value from `Receive` to see how many bytes have actually been received. That being said, I'd also agree with @Luaans answer - if you want messages, it's up to you to implement them (or pick a higher level network library that already provides such an abstraction)

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that i had to append the carriage return character to the end of the data i was sending.
It might have been a requirement on the server, i'm not sure, it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TCP doesn't work this way. It's as simple as that.

TCP is a stream-based protocol. That means that you shouldn't *ever* treat it as a message-based protocol (unlike, say, UDP). If you need to send messages over TCP, you have to add your own messaging protocol on top of TCP.

What you're trying to do here is send two separate messages, and receive two separate messages on the other side. This would work fine on UDP (which is message-based), but it will not work on TCP, because TCP is a stream with no organisation.

So yeah, `Flush` works just fine. It's just that no matter how many times you call `Flush` on one side, and how many times you call individual `Send`s, each `Receive` on the other end will get as much data as can fit in its buffer, with no respect to the `Send`s on the other side.

The solution you've devised (almost - just separate the strings with a single `\0`) is actually one of the proper ways to handle this. By doing that, you're working with messages on top of the stream again. This is called *message framing* - it allows you to tell individual messages apart. In your case, you've added *delimiters* between the messages. Think about writing the same data in a file - again, you'll need some way of your own to separate the individual messages (for example, using end lines).

Another way to handle message framing is using a *length prefix* - before you send the string itself, send it's length. Then, when you read on the other side, you know that between the strings, there should always be a length prefix, so the reader knows when the message ends.

Yet another way isn't probably very useful for your case - you can work with fixed-length data. So a message will always be exactly 100 bytes, for example. This is very powerful when combined with pre-defined message types - so message type 1 would contain exactly two integers, representing some coördinates, for example.

In either case, though, you'll need your own buffering on the receiving end. This is because (as you've already seen) a single receive can read multiple messages at once, and at the same time, it's not guaranteed to read the whole message in a single read. Writing your own networking is actually pretty tricky - unless you're doing this to actually *learn* network programming, I'd recommend using some ready technology - for example, Lindgren (a nice networking library, optimized for games but works fine for general networking as well) or WCF. For a chat system, simple HTTP (especially with the bi-directional WebSockets) might be just fine as well.

**EDIT:**

As Damien correctly noted, there seems to be another problem with your code - you seem to be ignoring the return value of `Read`. The return value tells you the amount of bytes you've *actually* read. Since you have a fixed-size persistent buffer on the receiving side (apparently), it means that every byte *after* the amount you've just read will still contain the *old* data. To fix this, just make sure you're only working with as much bytes as `Read` returned. Also, since this seems to indicate you're ignoring the `Read` return value altogether, make sure to properly handle the case when `Read` returns `0` - that means the other side has gracefully shutdown its connection - and the receiving side should do the same.

Comment: "Flush works just fine", but what does it even do then, what is it for in NetworkStream?

Comment: @Irdes Well, nothing, really. The buffering is done way lower than at the `NetworkStream` - the TCP protocol handles the buffering on its own. It's just that `Flush`ing wouldn't help anyway, your problem is with the receiving side, not the sender. `Flush`ing a TCP stream is still useful in some cases (TCP is designed for high-latency, low-throughput networks), but it doesn't make much difference for your use-case. For example, unless you send enough data, TCP will only send the data once every 200ms by default (on Windows).

Comment: @Irdes Handling that is very simple usign `TcpClient` - just set `TcpClient.NoDelay` to true. That said, it only makes sense if you're looking to reduce latency to a minimum - and TCP will always have higher latency than UDP.

Comment: It's not even the mismatch between `Send` and `Receive` calls here - the OP called `Receive` and had their buffer filled with 8 characters. They then called `Receive` again using the same buffer and received the next two characters. But because they didn't clear the buffer, and because they're not checking the return value from `Receive`, they're looking in the buffer and seeing 8 characters (2 new, and 6 not overwritten)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah, right. I didn't notice that :) I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Irdes Also, I've just finished a simple sample for a chat application as part of my networking samples. It's far from perfect (error handling is lacking, and the design is focused on making the sample clear, rather than being a good base for a real application), but it might help you a bit - https://github.com/Luaancz/Networking/tree/master/Networking%20Part%202.