# How to convert list items to ASCII Encodings in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, server, network-programming, client

I was developed client and server chat application using on Socket programming...

My question is, how to convert a list of string items into ASCII Encodings.
Is there any way to use it?

My server side List is this :

```
  public static List<string> NickNameList = new List<string>();
```

---

here, I add my client's nick names to the list.

```
                Socket socket = socketClient as Socket;
                byte[] bs = new byte[1024];
                int ks = socket.Receive(bs);

                string RecievedSocket = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bs, 0, ks);

                NickNameList.Add(RecievedSocket);
```

---

And Lastly, I was tried to send back the list to the client which I saved on my NickNameList in the server.

```
   ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
   socket.Send(asen.GetBytes(listBox1.Items.ToString()));
```

But I don't know how to get a list of clients not converting into a string. Is there a way to send a list directly with ASCII Encoding?

If you know anything about this, Please let me know...

Comment: Why someone didn't strike out the "ASCII" word from the Dictionary ten years ago? Why? You don't even have an european/american name & surname... You should hate the ASCII word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... if you hate ASCII then I'll help you :-)

In general, try to use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`. They have a constructor that asks for a `Stream` (the `NetworkStream` you get from the Tcp class) and an `Encoding` (you will use `Encoding.ASCII`).

- `BinaryWriter` side you use the `Write(int)` to write the length of the `List<>`, then you write the elements of the list with `Write(string)` (in a `for`/`foreach` cycle).
- `BinaryReader` side you `ReadInt32` how many elements you'll need to read, then in a `for` cycle you `ReadString()` them.

The `Write(string)`/`ReadString()` have a "trick": they prepend the length of the string they are writing/expect the length to be prepended. This because in a "pure" TCP connection there is no "message". You only have a stream of bytes, so you can't know how much long a string will be, unless you say it (or unless you use a specific value, like the byte 0, to specify the end of the string). We use the same "trick" to specify the length of the `List<>`: we prepend its length.

Fun sample of the server that sends a list of strings, and the client that reverse all the strings and send them back.

```
public static void Server()
{
    var lst = new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };

    int port = 15001;
    var localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

    var listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

    try
    {
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (client)
                using (var ns = client.GetStream())
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(ns, Encoding.ASCII, true))
                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ns, Encoding.ASCII, true))
                {
                    bw.Write(lst.Count);

                    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                    {
                        bw.Write(lst[i]);
                    }

                    var lst2 = new List<string>();

                    int count = br.ReadInt32();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        lst2.Add(br.ReadString());
                    }

                    foreach (string str in lst2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}", str);
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.Start();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }
}

public static void Client()
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Client");
    int port = 15001;

    using (var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port))
    using (var ns = client.GetStream())
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(ns, Encoding.ASCII, true))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ns, Encoding.ASCII, true))
    {
        var lst = new List<string>();
        int count = br.ReadInt32();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(br.ReadString());
        }

        foreach (string str in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client: {0}", str);
        }

        bw.Write(lst.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            var chars = lst[i].ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(chars);
            bw.Write(new string(chars));
        }
    }
}
```

Useful question about the working of `NetworkStream`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30499295/613130 (and how to send/receive messages)

Comment: So you are saying, I should convert the hole list to bytes and then getting from foreach /for cycle(loop) . Is it?

Comment: @SunguRuvin No, the `BinaryReader`/`Writer` will do the conversions for you. They accept directly a `string`